# Bootstrap 4 popover fetching data correctly but not when page is part of PHP include

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-4, popover

I have a PHP page that calls a second page using PHP include. The second page has a Bootstrap 4 popover that populates data from an ajax call in a bootstrap 4 popover to a third page (visit_grade_popover.php). The popover will not show the data from third page.

The popover works correctly and fetches the data from the third page (visit_grade_popover.php) if I just use the second page. It won't load the data into the popover if page 1 is using PHP include to show second page, which has the popover. Currently, the popover just displays Loading... but never loads the data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<a href="#" id="popover-trigger2" data-toggle="popover" title="Grade Distribution" data-content="Loading..." class="popover-ajax" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" data-report-date="<?php echo $row_RecordsetGrades['Report_Date']; ?>">
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popover-ajax').popover({
    html: true,
    delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
  });

  // Loop through each row in the table
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var course = row.find('td:eq(1)').text(); // Get the course value from the second column (index 1)
    var teacher = row.find('td:eq(2)').text(); // Get the teacher value from the third column (index 2)
    var reportDate = row.find('.popover-ajax').data('report-date'); // Get the report_date value from the data-report-date attribute

    var popoverTrigger = row.find('.popover-ajax');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'visit_grade_popover.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        course: course,
        teacher: teacher,
        report_date: reportDate
      },
      success: function(response) {
        popoverTrigger.attr('data-content', response);
      },
      error: function() {
        popoverTrigger.attr('data-content', 'Error occurred while fetching data.');
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked what the browser console has to say? This lacks details, but I am guessing that when you included the second file into the first, that probably changed the URL path, regarding the folder depth? So that you AJAX request probably runs into a 404 error now or something.